# Compiling error after change code Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have the problem that if I debug my code every time I change it i get a compiling error. 
Whenever I restart the server then everything runs again.

```
(0,0): error : Cannot create file: C:\Users\alex\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\a9393033\9993fb91\App_Code.pdb. 
The process cannot access the file because it is used by another process.
```

My Setup:

- Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.0.2
- .NET v4.0.30319

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134137/build-error-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-ano/44375377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wokring with ASP.NET, try to remove the `optimizeCompilations="true"` attribute in your web.config file. Also make sure you have the latest updates of VS installed.