# The file is locked by: "w3wp.exe" after windows update

Tags: visual-studio, iis, w3wp.exe

I' ve an ASP.NET CORE project with IIS, Im using this about 1 year without problems.
Yeserday I update windows 1909 to 21H2 and im getting all the time these errors on visual studio:

> "The process cannot acces the file ... (DLL) because it is used by
> another process"

> "Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: w3wp.exe"

So i can't publish updates on my software.

I see that on executing process, the w3wp.exe is duplicated when i try to publish.

[image: double w3wp.exe]

So now, to publish the project i must close manually all these processes and then publish it.
This "solution" works sometimes; but it's so realy realy boring
Is there a way to solve this error?
I tried to search many solutions, but nothing works.

Comment: "but it's really boring" - if you find yourself performing tasks manually repeatedly, then just automate it. Scripts can kill processes for you. In fact, your entire deployment should be automated to the point you should only need to click a single button or run a single script to deploy.

Comment: many times the publish not works when i try to kill process, so this can't be a solution

Comment: I'm searching a way to fix these issues with some tips like: go in settings and change 'x', or try to delete xyz file or something like this. Not "cover" the issues

Comment: Could you please check if the solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134137/build-error-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-ano) can help with your problem.

Comment: @HuryShen I tried to change release to debug but nothing. Then i tried to remove all files inside the folder and paste them again, but again not working.

Comment: Since your application works fine and the issue comes after you update windows, so I think you can create a support ticket on [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/) to ask microsoft engineer for help.