# Visual Studio 2010 SP1 is locking and preventing itself from building the project target assembly

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

I have a project, which contains various classes and user controls. Every once in a while, often on the second build attempt, Visual studio locks the project's target assembly and the build fails with the following error:

> Unable to copy file "obj\x86\Debug\MyProject.dll" to "bin\x86\Debug\MyProject.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\x86\Debug\MyProject.dll' because it is being used by another process.

This same issue was reported here: [VisualStudio2010 Debugging - The process cannot access the file ... because it is being used by another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690119/visualstudio2010-debugging-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-i/5273743#comment9953280_5273743). I tried a few of the presented answers, but none of them resolved the matter for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: sometimes it helps to change from Debug to Release; build it and then change back

Comment: Changing to Release, does let me do a Release build, but unfortunately changing it back to Debug was still locked up.

Answer (score -1):

I read somewhere it's a known issue and they're working on a hotfix - knowing Microsoft it should come out about the time Windows 9 does.

The current only real fix is to uninstall SP1, but since I can't be bothered doing that I just delete all the project files in the Debug folder, but you have to do this every time it throws the error. You can't use a program or batch file to do this since for some reason it completely locks the file and you have to wait ~5mins for the system to unlock and delete it.